# VB 2008 - SQL Server 2005 - DataGridView - update button - write changes to database

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005, datagridview

I'm new to vb.

Currently, I'm populating 'DataGridView1' with data from a table in a SQL Server 2005 database.
I need to be able to write back all changes made by simply clicking `btnupdate`

Related threads on this site handle specific cases and not all code is accepted by VS in my case so they're not really helpful.

So:

```
Private Sub btnupdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnupdate.Click
    'This needs to save the changes to the database'
End Sub
```

Is there a simple piece of code that I can insert?

thanks.

Comment: This is **way too broad** a question.... how do you connect to SQL Server? Raw ADO.NET with ad-hoc queries? ADO.NET with stored procedures? Something like Entity Framework? What does your data look like that you display in the `DataGridView` - and how is it stored in SQL Server 2005? You'll need to provide **a lot more relevant information** for us to be able to help you!

Comment: I connect to my server still only from vs2008 using the 'data connection' and 'data source' functions, and a sql username/pass. the data consists of a number of collumns with names and numbers, nothing but nvchar(50) and int, it's stored in one database on a server 2 stories down from here. I want my app to log on to the server on startup but I'm still trying to get that to work. I was gonna ask that in another thread

Answer (score 1):

The topic is broad. Below is a sample using DataTable and DataAdapter. DataTable is used to hold data from database and track changes made by user to specific rows when bound to the grid. The adapter generates the sql required to carry out commands of update and delete provided a valid SQL SELECT. There are many different ways to accomplish what you want, however, this is a sample of what you can do. After taking a look to the code below, you may want to dig deeper in specific classes to learn more about them and adapt them to your needs.

Note: Your *connection string* and variable names in your case may vary from what is shown in this listing:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmdBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim changes As DataSet
    Dim sql As String
    Dim i As Int32

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        sql = "select * from Product"
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            connection.Close()
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnupdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        '*** Process updates as made by the user in the datagridview control.
        Try
            cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
            changes = ds.GetChanges()
            If changes IsNot Nothing Then
                adapter.Update(changes)
            End If
            MsgBox("Changes Done")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Adapted from source: http://vb.net-informations.com/dataadapter/dataadapter-datagridview-sqlserver.htm

Comment: type 'SqlConnection' is not defined,
type 'SqlDataAdapter' is not defined,
type 'SqlCommandBuilder' is not defined,
       
This was the problem with the piece of code I found earlier.
Like I said: I'm still new to vb

Comment: .NET requires that you use correct namespace for classes. I have modified the code to reflect this, as you require the line: Imports System.Data.SqlClient at the top of your code. If you are totally new to .NET, I would suggest you not begin with Database access since it is not a trivial subject. Also, I highly recommend a book on ADO.NET.