# update columns in table using C# for current row in gridview control

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, datagridview, windows

How do i updated the Modified and ModifiedBy column in my gridview1 control based on the current one thats showing or is selected.

Currently i have the following but it seems to update everything:

```
string ConnectionString = "Data Source=C;Initial Catalog=tickets;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
Conn.Open();

SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter("UPDATE [tickets].[dbo].[UpdatedStat] SET MODIFIED = GETDATE(), MODIFEDBY = 'John' WHERE Person = 'John' AND ClosedDate IS NULL", Conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DA.Fill(dt);

if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    Conn.Close();
}
```

The problem is, how do update only the record/row in focus in my grid view? I basically click a button to move to the next row, so i need to update EACH record with my `ModifiedDate` and `Modified` name.

OH and the update code doesnt even work at all? I think i need an update command??

Comment: I have provided an answer to a similar question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759216/vb-2008-sql-server-2005-datagridview-update-button-write-changes-to-data/20760184#20760184 - Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I need it in C#.... The syntax is just confusing... :(

Comment: This also doesnt not get the current item in the gridview to update?